# Time dependent plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot point-by-point a sine wave in Python via Matplotlib, for which, each point, is added every *x* milliseconds, in order to obtain a smooth animation of the drawing.

This is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from math import sin

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [0]
line, = ax.plot(x, np.asarray(0))


def animate(i):
    x.append(x[-1]+0.04)
    line.set_xdata(np.asarray(x)*2*np.pi/5)
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(np.asarray(x)*2*np.pi/5))
    plt.draw()

def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 10, init_func=init, interval=40, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Which raises:

```
RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.
```

What did I mistaken? What is, in your opinion, the most efficient way to obtain this effect?

PS The time axis should stay fixed and not move, so it should be wider than the plot

Comment: your animation function doesn't return anything. the error message says it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you are getting the error because your `animate(i)` is not returning anything. You need to return `line,`. Secondly you are not using the `i`in `animate(i)` aswell.

Here is a simple sine curve animation from https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to 
animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have 
changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

There is additional inspiration in the link which might help you further.

Comment: Thank you. To get what I needed I changed the code a little bit to have the sine drawn slowly instead of a full sine moving

Answer (score 1):

### Animate should return a sequence of artist objects:

You should add:

`return line,` to the end of the animate function

```
def animate(i):
    x.append(x[-1]+0.04)
    line.set_xdata(np.asarray(x)*2*np.pi/5)
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(np.asarray(x)*2*np.pi/5))
    return line,
```

### Source:

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091682/runtimeerror-the-init-func-must-return-a-sequence-of-artist-objects)

[Simple Example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html)