# FuncAnimation: RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to plot real-time temperature data with the animation module from matplotlib in Python. I get the temperature data via USB connection from a Lake Shore 224 temperature monitor

Here is my adjusted code (source: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/graph-sensor-data-with-python-and-matplotlib/update-a-graph-in-real-time):

```py
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from lakeshore import Model224

# You can ignore the following try and except block, it's a workaround for a different small problem
try:
    from IPython import get_ipython
    get_ipython().magic('clear')
    get_ipython().magic('reset -f')
except:
    pass

# Create figure for plotting

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
xs = []
ys = []

myinstrument = Model224()

# This function is called periodically from FuncAnimation
def animate(i, xs, ys):
    # Read temperature from port A
    temperature_A = myinstrument.get_kelvin_reading('A')
    
    # Add x and y to lists
    xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
    ys.append(temperature_A)
    
    # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
    xs = xs[-20:]
    ys = ys[-20:]
    
    # Draw x and y lists
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)
    
    # Format plot
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
    plt.ylabel('Temperature [K]')

# Set up plot to call animate() function periodically

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func =  animate, fargs=(xs,ys), interval=10000, blit = True)
plt.show()
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.
```

At first, I did set as described in this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784710/the-animation-function-must-return-a-sequence-of-artist-objects):

```
blit = False
```

Which gives me no error message, but a blank white plot. Interestingly, it never enters the animate-Function.

Afterwards, I adjusted the code and added:

```
blit = True
```

To the function input, I got at least the following plot:

[image]

And I get the RuntimeError described above.

Still, I'm expecting a real-time temperature graph just like in the original source.

Comment: `xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))` is plotting strings on the x-axis, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Why is that? I had no problems with this one.

Comment: If you have only a few values, and they're equally spaced (e.g. every 5 minutes), then there probably won't be an issue. However, when passing strings to the axis, the api plots every value (which will cause overcrowding if there are many values), and spaces them evenly, even if the actual spacing is not even.

Comment: That's true, at first I tought there was no issue, but everytime I ran the code for a while, the x-axis became confusing. This was the reason I switched to PyQT5 because the x-axis get updated and scales automatically.  I'm sure this is also possible with my first approach, but I didn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using blitting, [as per the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html), you need to return the artists that change. The general approach for using `FuncAnimation` is to create a blank plot and save the `Line2D` object that it returns. Each loop you can update the data for that line using `line.set_data()` and then return the line for blitting. When using `FuncAnimation` properly, you don't need to worry about clearing the figure.

Since I don't have a sensor, I just produced some data at the start and slowly plot that in my example below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
N = 1000
xdata = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
ydata = np.sin(5*xdata)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [])
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right")
ax.set_ylabel("Temperature [K]")
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)

xs = []
ys = []

def animate(i, xs, ys):    
    xs.append(xdata[i])
    ys.append(ydata[i])
    
    xs = xs[-20:]
    ys = ys[-20:]
    
    line.set_data(xs, ys)
    ax.set_xlim(min(xs), max(xs))
    
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=N, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=10, blit=True)
fig.show()
```

Comment: At first, thanks for your help. Your code worked for me. The only thing it didn't do was updating the x-axis when using Qt. When I changed the window size (minimizing -> full picture -> minimizing ...), while running the code, it did work.