# Matplotlib FuncAnimation Step-by-Step Animation Function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, imshow

I am trying to use `matplotlib`'s `FuncAnimation` to make an animated video. Each frame is just a boolean `n` x `n` array visualised as white/black squares. I can do this successfully by defining all the arrays in advance and then going through them one by one. This uses code similar to [`matplotlib`'s example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html).

My items are rather large and I want to run the simulation for a long time. I thus don't want to create the entire list of arrays then go through them one by one. Instead, I want to define the `animate` function to do each step. Let me explain with a minimal non-working example. My actual example includes far larger arrays!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def create_video(n):
    global X
    X = np.random.binomial(1, 0.3, size = (n,n))
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    im = plt.imshow(X, cmap = plt.cm.gray)
    
    def animate(t):
        global X
        X = np.roll(X, +1, axis = 0)
        im.set_array(X)
    
    anim = FuncAnimation(
        fig,
        animate,
        frames = 100,
        interval = 1000 / 30,
        blit = True
    )
    
    return anim

anim = create_video(10)
```

This initialises some random `10` x `10` set of `0`/`1`s then just 'rolls' it at each step. I get an error.

> RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.

If I remove the `return anim`, replacing it with `pass`, and replacing `anim = create_video(10)` with `create_video(10)`, then I get a warning.

> UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely unintended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable that exists for as long as you need the Animation.

Clearly, I don't understand well enough [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html). What I want to happen is for the function `animate` to update the array `X`, by 'rolling' it one step, as well as doing `im.set_array(X)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091742/9214357):

> As the error suggests, and as can be seen e.g. in the
> [`simple_animation` example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/animation/simple_anim.html), but also from the [`FuncAnimation`
> documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html), the `init_func` as well as the updating `func` are
> supposed to return an iterable of artists to animate.
>
> The documentation does not say that this is actually only needed when
> using `blit=True`, but since you are using blitting here, it is
> definitely needed.

So you have two ways:

- add

  ```
  return im,
  ```

  to `animate` function
- set `blit = False` in `FuncAnimation`

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def create_video(n):
    global X
    X = np.random.binomial(1, 0.3, size = (n, n))

    fig = plt.figure()
    im = plt.imshow(X, cmap = plt.cm.gray)

    def animate(t):
        global X
        X = np.roll(X, +1, axis = 0)
        im.set_array(X)
        return im, 

    anim = FuncAnimation(
        fig,
        animate,
        frames = 100,
        interval = 1000/30,
        blit = True
    )

    plt.show()

    return anim

anim = create_video(10)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you. I feel very silly! In my previous version which created all the arrays first, then made the animation from them, I did have `return [im]` in the place you suggest! Thank you for helping me :)